# Eclipse DTP new driver definition

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, eclipse-dtp

I am trying to connect to Postgresql from Eclipse through Eclipse DTP.

I navigated to Window->Preference->Data Management-> Driver Definition

After that I chose PostgreSQL and tried to add the driver through the New Driver Definition Template. But everything seems to be greyed out and I am neither able to edit the driver name of add the jar file using the add button.
All buttons are disabled and greyed out.

Please Help.

[image: Jar]

[image: DriverName]

Comment: Hope you might have found the answer. If yes, please share.

Answer (score 0):

i always use Postgresql with dtp,works like a champ..
you can't create a driver from  Window->Preference->Data Management-> Driver Definition.

go to "data source explorer view" -> right click "new" -> pick "Postgresql"-> click on "new driver definition" ... then follow the wizard

===============

hope its helps

Answer (score 0):

On **Name/Type** tab, just expand the window like this :
[image]
then you can add jar/zip file on the **JAR List** tab